# Nested Routing is not displaying the right Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

I'm trying to display CollectionPage Component from ShopPage component as a nested route that receives collectionId as a param but I get an empty page.
These are my components.

Shop Page :

```
import React from 'react';
import CollectionsOverview from '../../components/collections-overview/collections-overview.component';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import CollectionPage from '../collection/collection.component';

const ShopPage = ({ match }) => (
    <div className='shop-page'>
        < Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview} />
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}/collectionId`} component={CollectionPage} />
    </div>
)

export default ShopPage;
```

CollectionPage Component :

```
import React from 'react';
import CollectionItem from '../../components/collection-item/collection-item.component';
import './collection.styles.scss';


const CollectionPage=({match})=>{
    console.log(match);
    return(
    <div className="collection-page">
        <h2>Collection Page</h2>
    </div>
)}

export default CollectionPage;
```

Comment: how do you visit that page?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/shop/hats     (for example )

Comment: so `hats` is a parameter

Comment: yes exactly, Im supposed to get that param dynamically from my redux state

Comment: so you should prefix it by `:` but i think the problem is in `match.path`

Comment: The first route works though

Comment: could you reproduce a simple example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-fog-0lfrr?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: here you go  [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-lalande-80j2g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: remove `exact` from `<Route path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />` in App.tsx check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-curie-pxf40?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `collectionId` is a parameter which should be prefixed by `:` like :

```
 <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`} component={CollectionPage} />
```

and remove `exact` from `<Route path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />` in App.tsx check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-curie-pxf40?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: I tried that and expected to get whatever I type after the current route as a param in the match object in the CollectionPage component props. But still, the route doesn't even work.

Comment: how do you visit that page?

Comment: localhost:3000/shop/hats (for example )